# Swaping textviews with dragging

Tags: android, drag, swap

I want to drage textview and swap their positions in android for re-arranging the words.Like:
Have he dog.
Now i want that i will drag "he" and place it in the position of have and then have will placed in this position of he automatically.
So is there any possible way to drag the textviews and swap their positions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

1) https://github.com/rfreedman/android-constrained-drag-and-drop-view

2) You can also try this tutorial (it will only work with API>11)

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality/attachment/app_end/

Make it as the answer if it helps you :)